# App not launch when using https in firebase dynamic link

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services, firebase-dynamic-links

I am using dynamic link for android

I am facing issue when clicking on https://example.page.link/test ,it's not launching app.
But if I change `https` to http://example.page.link/test it's opening my app

The second thing is, if app is not installed,it's redirected to play store with my app and then immediately redirecting to common page.

Is there any sample code for Android

What am I missing ? Do I have to change anything in my code?

Comment: DO you have `<intent-filter>` with `https` in manifest ? Add manifest entry with question .

Comment: see this URL [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38339032/how-to-open-a-deep-linking-uri-in-android]