# Kotlin, How to open application from url?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-activity

For example: in chrome you type "instagram.com/username", after loading will open instagram app with user profile activity

Comment: Take a look at https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking

Comment: Use `ACTION_VIEW` with your desired URL. If the app has registered a deep link, Android will open the associated activity. If not, Android will open a browser on the requested URL.

Comment: Take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38555465/4593476